# jQuery autocomplete Enter key - multiple events fire

Tags: jquery, events, firefox, autocomplete

I have an custom autocomplete dropdown that displays a list of items.The user can either select from the dropdown or enter some text in the text field and hit enter. I want to be able to differentiate between the user selecting item from the autocomplete dropdown and hitting enter vs hitting enter without selecting item from the dropdown. Currently with the code skeleton displayed below, I see that in firefox, when somebody selects the dropdown item using keyboard and hits enter, the select function within the autocomplete fires first followed by the enter key action present in the evtHandlers ie. the ajaxRedirect function which overwrites the result that the select function in custom autocomplete.  I want to prevent execution of ajaxRedirect when somebody selects from the dropdown using keyboard and hits enter key. Note: IE and Chrome seems to be handling it well, it does not fire ajaxRedirect function when selecting from the autocomplete dropdown and hitting enter.

```
Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function (opts) {
        this.fireAutoComplete(opts);
        this.evtHandlers(opts);
    }
    evtHandlers: function (opts) {
        $("#" + opts.currentEl).on('keypress', function (e) {
            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
            if (e.which == 13) {  
                self.ajaxRedirect(opts, $(this).val());
            }
        });
    }

    fireAutoComplete: function (opts) {

        $("#" + opts.currentEl).s4_autocomplete({
            select: function (src, id, fields) {

                //fire the function on selecting the dropdown item
            }
        });

    }
```